# How to sign token transaction in Serum Anchor

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

I have a simple contract using Serum Anchor (on Solana) that transfers tokens from one party to another. It is currently failing with:

`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

Full code from snippets below at: https://gist.github.com/h4rkl/700400f515ab0736fd6d9318d44b2dca

I'm setting up 4 accounts for the transaction:

```js
  let mint = null; // key for token mint
  let god = null; // main program account to pay from and sign
  let creatorAcc = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate(); // account to pay to
  let creatorTokenAcc = null; // token account for payment
```

I'm setting them up as follows:

```js
const [_mint, _god] = await serumCmn.createMintAndVault(
      program.provider,
      new anchor.BN(MINT_TOKENS),
      undefined,
      MINT_DECIMALS
    );
    mint = _mint;
    god = _god;

    creatorTokenAcc =await serumCmn.createTokenAccount(
      program.provider,
      mint,
      creatorAcc.publicKey
    );
```

And then I make the payment with the following method:

```js
const INTERACTION_FEE = 200000000000000;
await program.rpc.interaction(new anchor.BN(INTERACTION_FEE), {
      accounts: {
        from: god,
        to: creatorTokenAcc,
        owner: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      },
    });
```

In the contract that the method is triggering my interaction process is as follows:

```rust
pub fn interaction(ctx: Context<Interaction>, interaction_fee: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info().clone(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info().clone(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.owner.clone(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.clone();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        token::transfer(cpi_ctx, interaction_fee)?;
       
        Ok(())
    }
```

I have setup the Interaction `pub struct` with the following params:

```rust
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Interaction<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
    from: CpiAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account("from.mint == to.mint")]
    to: CpiAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(signer)]
    owner: AccountInfo<'info>,
    token_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

As far as I can tell the params are correct, and the `god` account owns the wallet as the payer and is the signer. Why is this failing, and what am I missing? I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: hi can you update your codes i wanna show new version of that ccodes .

Comment: Working version here.

https://gist.github.com/awcchungster/f865afefcda74d1985c066fa26775a7c

Answer (score 3):

Answered [here](https://twitter.com/armaniferrante/status/1428179785738428419) by the legendary Armani Ferrante:

> Your  `to` account isn't marked mutable.

Comment: What does it have to be mutable though?

Comment: @DaveTheAl since it is recieving funds it needs to eb marked mutable.